# Internal Interfaces & Classes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, interface

I'm refactoring some code I didn't write, that contains business logic and proprietary algorithms I don't want to expose. All the code is currently marked as internal; for testing purposes, and to ensure I don't break existing clients/services, I wanted to switch them to use interfaces, and implement those interfaces.

I've marked my classes as internal and their members as protected internal, and my interfaces as internal, but to use the internal interfaces, I've had to make several of my properties public.

I believe, and with some limited testing, seemed to have proven that only friend assemblies, and classes in my assembly, can use these internal interfaces and classes.

As long as both the class, and interface remain internal, even if some of the methods and the properties are marked public, will they be exposed at all?

It doesn't seem so, but I'm looking for anything I might have missed.

Comment: Unless you're working in a partial trust scenario, accessibility is just asking nicely not use to use something. It in no way protects propietary code[Except by giving the obfuscator more leeway].

Comment: Classes can't be protected unless they're nested.

Comment: corrected, meant the class as internal, and its members as protected internal

Comment: @Brian: if the class is `internal` then yes, those attributes would be "protected", so to speak.  Same as if they were `public` attributes on an `internal` class.  Since the class is invisible, the attributes are as well (provided of course the class isn't knowable through a more public interface....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean protected as in a using assembly can't directly use them, then yes, if the `interface` and `class` are marked `internal`, then they won't be visible outside the assembly.  Think of the access level on the interfaces and members as being separate locks to get through.

If you can see the `interface` at its access level, then you can store a reference to it, and then if you can see the properties/methods at their access levels, then you can call/set/get them.

Keep in mind, though, as @phoog points out that `protected internal` is a bit looser than `internal`.

All this said, if your `internal` class implements a `public` interface, and those properties are part of a `public` interface as well, they could be visible...  But that's really getting obscure...

```
public interface IVisible
{
    string VisibleProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class InvisibleClass : IVisible
{
    public string VisibleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In the above, you **could** refer to the class `InvisibleClass` through an `IVisible` reference in a different assembly *if* you could find a way to construct or receive a reference to it (for instance, if it were returned from a factory method inside of the original assembly).

All this aside, if your question is that you want to avoid them from being examined through a decompiler, reflection, etc, that's a *different* question...

Comment: "But that's really getting obscure..." -- Actually, if you spend some time examining the BCL with ILDASM or a similar tool, you'll find this approach is very common.

Answer (score 2):

A public member is only as accessible as its type ("Normally, the accessibility of a member is not greater than the accessibility of the type that contains it. However, a public member of an internal class might be accessible from outside the assembly if the member implements interface methods or overrides virtual methods that are defined in a public base class.").

Don't be bitten by the `protected internal` problem, though: a `protected internal` member is available to derived classes outside the assembly.

References:

Accessibility levels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Access modifiers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: I can't think offhand of a way of making them accessible outside the assembly if all the classes and interfaces are `internal`.  But rather than `protected internal`, why not use `internal` (making them available only in your assembly) or `protected` (making them available only to derived classes)?  What value does `protected internal` provide?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Since you can't access internal classes from outside (apart from friend assemblies), you can't access any of its methods either, even if they're public.

You *could* access an internal class from outside it it has a public base class or implements a public interface. But you could only access the public methods in that class that are both in the base class (or interface) and overridden in the sub class (so the method should also be `virtual` or part of an interface - which also makes it `virtual`). For this, you'd have to obtain an instance to the class referenced by a super class (or interface) variable.